# Display strings on JtextArea

Tags: java

Cant display words (strings) on textfield or textarea on my code.
I got the link https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/68405/jogo-da-memoria-com-chat-gr%C3%A1fico

These are the most important lines:

```
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

private JTextArea textArea;
int player;
private DataInputStream input;
private JTextField id;


JPanel middlePanel=new JPanel();     
JTextArea display=new JTextArea(12,12);
display.setEditable(true); //false
JScrollPane scroll=new JScrollPane(display);
scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
middlePanel.add(scroll);
window.add(middlePanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
display.setText("Player 1");


middlePanel.setBorder(new TitledBorder(new EtchedBorder(),"Informações                            Chat"));        
JTextArea display2=new JTextArea(12,12);
display2.setEditable(true); 
JScrollPane scroll2=new JScrollPane(display2);
scroll2.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
middlePanel.add(scroll2);
window.add(middlePanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
window.pack();
window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
window.setVisible(true);    
window.resize(700,500);
```

In these line i want to display. "You are Player 1"

```
public void run()
{
    // Primeiro a jogar jogador 1, segundo 2
    try 
    {          
        player=input.readChar();
        textArea.setText("You are player \""+ player + "\"");
        myTurn=(player == '1' ? true : false);
    }
```

To sum: the text between " " isn´t printed on the textarea(or textfield), it only show empty white squares with vertical bars.

The only text that appears on screen is : display.setText("Player 1");

Comment: Does your input.readChar() trhow exceptions?

Comment: I think yes, also that run() function below have this code: ....catch ( IOException e ) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();         
        }
        while ( true ) 
        {
            try 
            {
                String s = input.readUTF();
                processMessage( s );
            }
            catch ( IOException e ) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();         
            }
        }

Comment: On that run(): for testing i add this: display.setText("Player 2");  -> Error cannot find simbol, variable display, Class memoryGame7. The "display" command word, is in black color not in green.

Comment: Also i got a error in this code: public static void main(String[] args)
    {        
        ServidorMult2 game = new ServidorMult2();
        game.addWindowListener( new WindowAdapter() 
        {
            public void windowClosing( WindowEvent e )
            {
                System.exit( 0 );
            }
        });

Comment: I think you 'd better rewrite your code and test piece by piece. It seems that your project is full of errors.